# How to write the set difference code without using memberchk and subtract?

Tags: prolog

How to write the set difference code without using memberchk and subtract?

```
 set_difference( [], _, [] ) :- !.
 set_difference( [A|C], B, D ) :-
      memberchk( A, B ), !,
 subtract( C, B, D ).
 set_difference( [A|B], C, [A|D] ) :-
      subtract( B, C, D ).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to recursively go down list `A`, constructing list `Aout`, covering tow cases:

- An element `X` at the tip of `A` is in list `B` -> forget about `X`, recurse (really, fullfill an inductive definition for `my_set_difference(A,B,Aout)`)
- An element `X` at the tip of `A` is not list `B` -> retain `X` for `Aout`, recurse (really, fullfill an inductive definition for `my_set_difference(A,B,Aout)`)
- Base case: `A` is empty. Evidently, `Aout` must be empty too.

The above are naturally mapped to two clauses for the predicate `my_set_difference(A,B,Aout)`.

As you don't have `member/2` to check whether *the tip of `A` is in list `B`*, you need to program `look(X,B)` which looks for `X` in `B` by scanning B. This is completely analogous to the above, but you can stop early if you find `X` in `B`.

Have at it, it's an easy exercise.